# Ubuntu 12.10 libgtk-3-0 Missing Symbols

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gtk3, apt

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and somehow my libgtk-3-0 became screwed up. When trying to run many different apps, I get errors like:

```
gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_action_group_action_state_changed
```

I've tried to reinstall libgtk-3-0:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk-3-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But still I get this problem - several undefined symbols from libgtk-3.so.0 when trying to run various apps. There is no problem booting the system. How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

My version of libgtk is installed as:

```
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0 -> libgtk-3.so.0.400.2
```

Comment: Do you have an older version of `libgtk-3` installed? You could check if the symlinks are correct. `libgtk-3.so.0` should be a symlink, check where it points with `ls -l /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0`.

Comment: I added my version above - how can I update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 'ldd' to figure out that I had the wrong versions of the libcairo and libgtk in a seperate directory. The libraries were linking against this wrong version. I removed the wrong versions, rebooted, and everything worked.

```
ldd /usr/bin/gedit
```