# Why after reboot IDE Eclipse print error?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, gtk

After installing IDE Eclipse mars.2 from official site's installer for linux64 I write some "Hello worlds's!" and all working. But later, after I reboot machine something happening with IDE and any projects not compiling, Eclipse closing with error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/user/eclipse/java-latest-released/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/user/eclipse/java-latest-released/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/user/eclipse/java-latest-released/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /home/user/eclipse/java-latest-released/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 15800d
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-install /home/user/eclipse/java-latest-released/eclipse
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/user/eclipse/java-latest-released/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

Strating from console sent this error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: pango_renderer_set_alpha
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I tried to reinstall from installer and tried starting from extracted archive from official site, but every time until machine not rebooted, all Ok. Also I tried remove oracle-java8 and installing openjdk-8, but I got the same result. I tried this topic [Ubuntu 12.10 libgtk-3-0 Missing Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993659/ubuntu-12-10-libgtk-3-0-missing-symbols), but it not helped.

My "uname -a":

```
Linux WORKSTATION 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.5-1 (2016-02-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My "java -version":

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

Anyone have the same problem earlier?